# Disallow subclasses from overriding Java method

Tags: java, class, methods, subclass

Suppose I have a method in a Java class, and I don't want any subclass of that class to be able to override that method. Can I do that?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can declare the method to be `final`, as in:

```
public final String getId() {
   ...
}
```

For more info, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

Comment: This is so obvious, why didn't I think of this?

Comment: Can cause Problems when using 'JavassistLazyInitializer'.
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=997278

Comment: Beware, it will cause issues with Spring `@Component`: child class is a `@Component` that inherits from the non-component parent class and this parent class has at least one `final` method. This method will not be wrapped into proxy object and might throw an exception when working with properties that should have been initialized with non-null values, so you might get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 10):

Simply make the method **final**.

Answer (score 4):

If your method is not part of your builded API and isn't directly called by subclasses, prefer simply making your method `private`.

If your class hierarchy is contained in a single package, make your method in package scope (without keyword of scoping). Thus, only outside world (included your other own packages) can't access it and therefore can't override it.

If your method isn't really part of your API but has to be visible by subclasses even external, prefer make it `protected` and `final`

Finally if your method is part of your API, make it `public` and `final`.